# Why wont identical code produce the same result in my browser as it does in Codeply?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

[Codeply link](https://www.codeply.com/go/RmXlEZfi8z)

There is no Javascript linked and some of the classes are not referred in the given CSS. Is there anything else I'm missing.

Sorry if it's a bad question, I'm an amateur.

[image: This is the result it produces in my browser in Web view.]

[image: When clicking the hamburger icon]

Comment: Make sure you're including Bootstrap CSS, Bootstrap JS and jQuery.

Comment: I have. I'm opening it from my localhost, could that cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to add the viewport for my browser window.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">
```